# Bootstrap card - width should fit content of child

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, card

Following example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">Status</div>
            <div class="col-7 d-flex">
                TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center content-height">
      Main Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Results in:

[image]

I would like the width of the card to fit the content.
How to achieve this?

**Update1 -** Answer to @Dimitar Cetelev
When i remove d-flex ist just breaks the content:

[image]

**Update2**

Changing to *col-auto* works well. But now the columns wont have the same width:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">Status</div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              StatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatus
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">Workflow</div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              WorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWork
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">API</div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              ApiApiApiApiApiApi
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center content-height">
      Main Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Results in:

[image]

Desired outcome without setting width of card to a fix-px:
[image]

Comment: I reckon some of your other classes are applying some form or width restriction (or no horizontal scrolling enabled). The Bootstrap classes alone would usually take care of responsiveness.

Comment: @AldinBradaric
There are no other classes. The shown example is everything in app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove `d-flex` class

```
<div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">Status</div>
 <div class="col-7">
 TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace class `col-5` and `col-7` with `col-auto`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">Status</div>
            <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center content-height">
      Main Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 1**

Reverted the changes from previous update.

Remove `d-flex` class and add `style="width:inherit"`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="card" style="width:inherit">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">Status</div>
            <div class="col-7">
              StatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatusStatus
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">Workflow</div>
            <div class="col-7">
              WorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWorkWork
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="width: inherit;">
            <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">API</div>
            <div class="col-7">
              ApiApiApiApiApiApi
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center content-height">
      Main Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note for smaller viewports, The card will contain the content by breaking the text if it is lengthy. This will avoid horizontal scrolling.